# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_messaging@132166593' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter

How to fix this issue `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_messaging@132166593' has not been initialized.)`

I had tried to used this method

```
late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;


getToken() async {
    String? token = await _messaging.getToken();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .update({'token': token});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getToken();
  }
```

or change to use `Future<void> getToken() async {`

But I still get the error. How can I do?

Comment: please change to this way  Future<void> getToken() async {

Comment: where did you call it's firbase instence ......?

Comment: @JintoJoseph still get error...

Comment: @JintoJoseph same page I had used `late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;`

Comment: The error is simple. You have not set any value for `_messaging` but you are using it.

Comment: don't use late i will give an eg :     FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

Comment: Either set value to `_messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance` in the method or set it while initializing

Comment: please remove late keyword from instance

Comment: @JintoJoseph Ok, I got it... I forgot has this ways could used.... thx bro